# String Hex to byte, vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net, byte

I'm struggling with an easy task. At least it looks like it should be, at first sight.  I have a `TextBox` that contains HEX strings.  They are always two hex digits in length (e.g. `AA`). I want to convert `textbox3.Text` to a `Byte`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim checking As String = textbox3.Text
Dim a = Convert.ToByte(checking)
RichTextBox1.Text = a.ToString
```

But it throws a `SystemFormatException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Convert.ToByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Convert_ToByte_System_String_System_Int32_) method provides an overload which takes a string argument followed by a number specifying the base of the value in the string.  Hexadecimal is base-16.  So, for instance:

```
Dim checking As String = textbox3.Text
Dim a As Byte = Convert.ToByte(checking, 16)
RichTextBox1.Text = a.ToString()
```