# Hex grouped by Byte encoded by HMAC SHA-1 to Hex grouped by 2 Byte

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption, hmacsha1

What I am attempting to do is take the string (HEX Byte)

AA BB CC DD EE FF

Use a predefined ky

Encode using HMAC SHA-1 (yes, I know it's old - but there is a reason)

and Convert it to HEX 2 Bytes and produce the result that starts like this

6f87 4348 6895 ae6d ab2d blcd

The following code

```
 Function ReturnAKey() As String
        Try
            Dim vEncoder As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
            Dim vKey() As Byte = vEncoder.GetBytes("85 44 E3 B4 7E CA 58 F9 58 30 43 F8")
            Dim vText() As Byte = vEncoder.GetBytes("AA BB CC DD EE FF")
            Dim vHMACSHA1 As New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(vKey)
            Dim vHashCode() As Byte = vHMACSHA1.ComputeHash(vText)
            Dim vHash As String = BitConverter.ToString(vHashCode)
            Return vHash.ToLower

        Catch ex As Exception
            EmailError(ex, 24, "TestPage")
            Return "Error"
        End Try
    End Function
```

returns

a0-ae-11-53-f9-fa-fc-65-04-a3-19-54-dd-54-cc-04-df-70-e1-cd

that would be

a0ae 1153 f9fa.....

and is not what I am looking for.

Any pointers please?

Comment: Your input is wrong. `vEncoder.GetBytes` does not decode the hex string. Use a Hex decoder instead.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Assuming you are using vb.net (you missed to mention that): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016764/string-hex-to-byte-vb-net

Comment: Changing vKey to  Dim vKey As Byte = Convert.ToByte("85 44 E3 B4 7E CA 58 F9 58 30 43 F8", 16) causes a Byte cannot be converted to Byte() issue further down. Did I miss something? Oh, I never add VB to tags as too many people skip it - converting from C# is better than no response :-)

Comment: Hex strings usually don't contain spaces -> remove them. If you don't tag vb.net than you should at least use `.net`.